# 500 error in administrator

Tags: administration, error-pages

A new error on my website occured. I think I did not make any changes that could cause this problem.

I can login in admin normally and then when I click on everything except installed components there is 500 server error. In error logs I can find nothing about it.

Any sugestions please?

Thank you! Filip

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: I use version 3.4.1

Comment: By staying on 3.4.1, you're leaving yourself vulnerable to 2 very important security issues that have arisen recently. Please update to 3.4.8 immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to try (assuming you can get to some or all of these pages):

- update to the latest version of Joomla (if you haven't already)
- update third party extensions to the latest versions
- switch to the alternative admin template to see if the issue is
  template related
- check if you have any third party administrator modules installed and
  if so, temporarily disable these to see if this helps
- similarly, check what third party plugins are installed and
  temporarily disable these to see if this helps

Some other things to try are:

- rename your `.htaccess` file to `.htaccess.old` and copy the default
  `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` to test if the issue may be caused by
  something in your `.htaccess` file
- temporarily disable Search Engine Friendly URLs and URL Rewriting to see if this helps (if you can't get to Global Configuration in the back-end, edit the `configuration.php` file and set `public $sef = '0';` and `public $sef_rewrite = '0';`
- back up your website and try running the "Reinstall Joomla core files" option in Components -> Joomla Update

Also check with your hosting company whether they have any ideas (e.g. could mod_security be causing this?).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Linux, make sure installed components have correct permissions.